# Is it possible to update cart total using wpdb query or in ajax call in woocommerce wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, php-7, hook-woocommerce

As per my client HTML design there is no cart page design provided instead of cart they want to display `product name, image , price , sub-total and total` in **checkout page** and calculate all things in checkout page.

They provided checkout page design like

In this page once user fill up form and click to continue it'll go to next

[image]

**Second Page**

In this page , First form fill-up data will be display and ask for choose shipping method, after choose method right side total will be update and click to continue it'll go to next

[image]

**Third page**....

In this page , showing previous page details and once click on pay now button a order will create.

[image]

I don't have any idea how can I manage this scenario but I have tried to manage this things using jQuery ajax but once I came to second page , I want to update total price based on change shipping method.

I have tried following ways with different hooks but it'll not work.

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function custom_calculated_total( $total, $cart ){
    echo "dsfsd";exit();
    return round( $total - ($total * 0.15), $cart->dp );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment','doAjax' );
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $wc_price ) {

    $wc_price = 10.5;   
    return $wc_price;
}
```

Once I used this hook total automatically updated without choosing any shipping method.

Also I have tried below ajax call on change shipping method for update cart total based on shipping method price.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'checkout_billing_email_js_ajax' );
function checkout_billing_email_js_ajax() {
    // Only on Checkout
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(document).on("click", ".shipping_method" ,function(e) {   
           //alert($(this).val()) 
            $.ajax({
                type:    'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
              //    url: cart_ajax.ajax_url,

                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                data: {
                    'action': 'ajax_order',
                    'fields': $('form.checkout').serializeArray(),
                    'user_id': <?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result); // For testing (to be removed)
                },
                error:   function(error) {
                    console.log(error); // For testing (to be removed)
                }
            });
        });
    });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

**Callback function method one**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'submited_ajax_order_data');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'submited_ajax_order_data');

function submited_ajax_order_data()
{
    global $woocommerce;

    $valorTotal = 10.5;

    WC()->cart->total = $valorTotal;
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    wc_price($valorTotal);*/
    $woocommerce->cart->set_total($woocommerce->cart->total + $valorTotal);
}
```

**Callback function method 2**: not working when I called a action hook in callback function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'submited_ajax_order_data');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'submited_ajax_order_data' );

function submited_ajax_order_data()
{
    add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'custom_cart_total' );
}

function custom_cart_total() {
    WC()->cart->total *= 10.25;
    var_dump( WC()->cart->total);
}
```

I know this is huge question but someone help me how can I do this things.( I want update cart total based on change shipping method)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook to add a discount and automatically change the order total.

It is also possible to use the `woocommerce_calculated_total` hook but then you will not have track of the discount applied *(if you have to recalculate the order total one day, unless you add a custom order meta)*.

Using `WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');` you will get an array with the ids of the shipping methods chosen by the customer.

I created two variables:

- **`$chosen_method_id`**: returns the id of the chosen shipping method and you can use it if you want to check a specific method for a specific shipping zone (for example `local_pickup:6`)
- **`$chosen_method`**: returns the type of shipping method to use if you want to check only if it is `flat_rate`, `free_shipping` or `local_pickup`

You choose the one you want to use.

Then:

```
// adds a custom discount to the cart based on the shipping method chosen
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_discount_based_on_shipping_method', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_discount_based_on_shipping_method( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // returns an array with the ids of the selected shipping methods
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

    if ( empty( $chosen_methods ) ) {
        return $total;
    }

    // get the shipping method id (for example: "flat_rate:1")
    $chosen_method_id = $chosen_methods[0];
    // get the shipping method (for example: "flat_rate", "free_shipping" or "local_pickup")
    $chosen_method = explode( ':', $chosen_method_id )[0];

    switch ( $chosen_method ) {
        case 'flat_rate':
            // 15% of discount
            $percentage = 15;
            break;
        case 'free_shipping':
            // 10% of discount
            $percentage = 10;
            break;
        case 'local_pickup':
            // 20% of discount
            $percentage = 20;
            break;
    }

    // gets cart contents total
    $cart_total = $cart->cart_contents_total;
    $discount = $cart_total * $percentage / 100;
    
    if ( isset( $discount ) && $discount > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( __( "Discount", 'woocommerce' ), -$discount );
    }
 
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*